Apache Vhost redirection on wrong subdomain
I have an issue with Apache vhosts. I requested redirection from HTTP to HTTPS (5001=http and 5002=https). The problem is that I’m experiencing a redirection from one domain to another, even though I never set this rule.
Could someone explain why this is happening?
My VHosts
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub2.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.sub2.domain.com

    Redirect permanent / https://sub2.domain.com/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub2_domain
    ServerName sub2.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.sub2.domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domain.key

    <Directory /var/www/sub2_domain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub2_domain_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:5001>
    ServerName sub1.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.sub1.domain.com

        Redirect permanent / https://sub1.domain.com:5002/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:5002>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/sub1_domain
    ServerName sub1.domain.com
    ServerAlias www.sub1.domain.com

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/domain.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/domain.key

    <Directory /var/www/sub1_domain>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require ip 192.168.1.0/24
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/sub1_domain_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

Apache display
VirtualHost configuration:
*:5001                 sub1.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub1_domain.conf:1)
*:5002                 sub1.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub1_domain.conf:8)
*:80                   sub2.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub2_domain.conf:1)
*:443                  sub2.domain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/sub2_domain.conf:8)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
Mutex fcgid-proctbl: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex mpm-accept: using_defaults
Mutex fcgid-pipe: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33

My cUrl request
C:\Users\user>curl -sv -o nul sub1.domain.com
* Host sub1.domain.com:80 was resolved.
* IPv6: (none)
* IPv4: 192.168.1.201
*   Trying 192.168.1.201:80...
* Connected to sub1.domain.com (192.168.1.201) port 80
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: sub1.domain.com
> User-Agent: curl/8.7.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Date: Sat, 17 Aug 2024 19:31:10 GMT
< Server: Apache/2.4.61 (Debian)
< Location: https://sub2.domain.com/
< Content-Length: 328
< Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
<
{ [328 bytes data]
* Request completely sent off
* Connection #0 to host sub1.domain.com left intact

Thanks

You configured the VirtualHost on port 5001, but your curl request did not specify a port and therefore connected to the default port 80 instead.
Since httpd cannot find a matching <VirtualHost :80> for the requested domain, it uses configuration from the first (topmost) VirtualHost for that port.
If you want both domains to be accessible without needing to specify the port number, then both of the plaintext VirtualHosts should be on the same port 80 (and both HTTPS VirtualHosts on the same port 443).
If you specifically do want different port numbers for some reason, but want to avoid the wrong redirect in case the visitor forgets to specify the port number, then create a new VirtualHost on port 80 that just serves an error message (e.g. returns error 400) and place it above all other VirtualHosts.

Alright! I understand the behavior better now, but I would prefer not to define an error for each subdomain and handle this in a common way. I tried adding a 404 return at the top for all requests with , but now when I try to display pages in HTTPS, I get the error 'SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG.' Could you please explain why this is happening?

Each port, not each subdomain – you need one such 'default' VirtualHost per port. You can group HTTP ports into one VirtualHost and HTTPS ports into another, but you can't group both HTTP and HTTPS into the same vhost because the SSLEngine setting is per-vhost (for historical reasons from before the era of "name-based vhosts") – so you're getting the error because Apache now thinks 443 is a plain HTTP port, not an HTTPS port. (I think it takes the SSL/non-SSL state from the first vhost too. This certainly gets confusing now, but it dates back to "one IP per vhost" era.)

In short, you need a <VirtualHost *:80 *:5001> and a <VirtualHost *:443 *:5002>, the latter with SSLEngine.

It works ! Thanks !
